# iPhone Jan 1, 1970 bug on Android?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, date-and-time, nexus-6

I was just wondering if this bug is on Android as well. I really want to try it but if it is, I don't want to ruin my phone. I mainly just want to know if I need to protect my phone's time and date from idiots at my school.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related reports around Android. And it simply soft-bricks the device. You can factory reset an Android device using recovery mode. If that doesn't work, flash it. No problem.

Comment: So if I did it, it would only be a soft brick? Alright, good to know.

Comment: Google would answer this, the answer is mixed... Although none seem to brick in anyway (soft or hard), just result in an error, or nothing happens.

Comment: Just did this on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1. Setting the date & time to 1970-01-01 00:07:31+07:30 didn't crash or anything. I couldn't set it lower than that since it would make the UNIX time value negative, which is invalid. Only common error like "Play Store cannot connect due to wrong time" occurred, but other than that, nothing serious.

Comment: Note: I could even make it Dec 31, 1969 by setting the timezone to +13:00, changing the date & time to Jan 1, 1970 13:01, then changing the timezone to -11:00. Still, nothing happened.

Comment: Additional note: it seems I forgot the most important part of iOS bug: reboot. Well, I tried once again setting the date to 31 Dec 1969 and then rebooting.. and it didn't brick the device. I'd say Android has placed safety precaution for this (basically, you can't set the UNIX time to 0 or negative)

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and describe the bug you're asking about. Most people here won't have any idea what "the iPhone bug" is.

Answer (score -2):

Possibly, the error is known as Unix Epoch and since both iPhone and Android use parts of the UNIX code (iPhone from Darwin which is based off BSD, based off UNIX and Android based off Linux, based off Unix). Android does not let you go further down than January 2, 1970 from my experience, so possibly.

Comment: Well, that would be smart, sadly, I was able to change the date to Jan 1, 1970. But, I changed it back right away. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're mixing up meaning of terms. Being "based off"(sic) means "being a derivative" of something. Linux is not a derivative of Unix but it was originally designed to be Unix-like,  to be compatible with Unix. It doesn't, in any fashion, imply that Linux inherited the code, and as such, the vulnerability in the code of Unix. See [Does Linux use original Unix code or do they share the idea?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103964)